# Preventing Internet Explorer from "remembering" an old SSL certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, troubleshooting, ssl, certificate

A website I'm using has switched recently from a GoDaddy SSL certifcate to a StartCom certificate, which works fine in most cases. The original GoDaddy certificate expired last year.

However, in Internet Explorer (multiple versions 8-9, and on several different machines) IF that website was first visited via ssl before the certificate was changed to the StartCom one, there is a certificate error warning. When approving the exception IE shows that it doesn't recognize that a new certificate is installed and still caches somehow the old expired certificate.

I've tried clearing the SSL cache, temporary internet files, restarting IE, and even doing a complete browser reset (via Internet Options > Advanced), but the error persists.

How can this be permanently solved?

[image]

[image]